# Split string in php into address and phone numbers (mobile and fax)

Tags: php, string, split

:)

I am trying to split a string that is made of a street address and two phone numbers.

This is the var_dump of the variable **$string**

> string(74) " **Via Alsazia 3 Scala A Int 1 35127 PADOVA (PD) 049 774266
>   049 775756** "

I tried this to split each one piece with this code:

```
$split = preg_split(')', $string);
$address = $split[0];
$split_two =preg_split(' ' ,  $split[1]);
$fax = $split_two[0];
$mobile = $split_two[1];
```

but it gives me only this

> **V**

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: I suggest you insert a delimiter (**@-@**) between the address and the number and then you can just use `explode('@-@', $string)`, and you will get an array where `[0] => "address"` and `[1] => "phone"`.

Comment: I understand , but the string its defined by another user.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Doralb5 so the user inputs this via input field or...?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its a website , I am trying to extract data.

Comment: Using simple_html_dom . Problem is that this information its stored in this line {<strong><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Via Alsazia 3 Scala A Int 1 35127 PADOVA  (PD) <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 049 774266 <i class="fa fa-fax"></i> 049 775756 <br></strong>} so i can use only the <strong> selector and parse its text

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it without regex:

```
$parts = explode(' ',$str);
$phone1 = array_pop($parts);
$phone1 = array_pop($parts)." ".$phone1;
$phone2 = array_pop($parts);
$phone2 = array_pop($parts)." ".$phone2;
```

.. assumes the phone numbers are always in the same format.

here's a fiddle: https://3v4l.org/Qp0kS

Answer (score 0):

you definitely need to enable warnings display

anyway, to fix you problem you can try:

```
<?php
$string = " Via Alsazia 3 Scala A Int 1 35127 PADOVA (PD) 049 774266 049 775756 ";

$split = explode(')', trim($string)); // note trim and explode
$address = $split[0];
$split_two = explode(' ' ,  trim($split[1])); // note trim
$fax = $split_two[0].' '.$split_two[1]; // note indexes
$mobile = $split_two[2].' '.$split_two[3]; // note indexes

echo 'fax '.$fax."<br>\n";
echo 'mobile '.$mobile."<br>\n";
?>
```

another variant is:

```
<?php
$string = " Via Alsazia 3 Scala A Int 1 35127 PADOVA (PD) 049 774266 049 775756 ";

preg_match('/^([^\)]+)\) +(\d+ \d+) +(\d+ \d+)$/', trim($string), $matches);

$address = $matches[1];
$fax = $matches[2];
$mobile = $matches[3];

echo 'address '.$address."<br>\n";
echo 'fax '.$fax."<br>\n";
echo 'mobile '.$mobile."<br>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use below [regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/WACTOX/1)

```
(.*?)(\d{3}\s\d{6})\s(\d{3}\s\d{6})$
```

First group lazy matches any characters - it is the address

Second and third groups match phone numbers at the end of the line in the following format:

> 3-digit-number space 6-digits-number

Comment: Thought about it. Anyway its a good way. But unfortunately sometimes they have another format like "Giudecca 187 30133 Venezia (VE) 349/1277065 0 "

Comment: For the variation string you could split the address and phones using the province code ( such as `PD`) , and then deal with less predictable format for phones.